# Inserting a row in MYSQL using java jdbc by taking an input from user

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, insert

I am using following code but still getting error

```
public void insertData(){  
String ch="y";
while(!"n".equals(ch)){
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    int i;
    String s;
    System.out.println("Enter new id");
    i=sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter new filename");
    s=sc.next();
    String sql = "INSERT INTO srt(id,file) " +
                   "VALUES (i, s)";
    try {
        st.executeUpdate(sql);
    } 
    catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Database_connect.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    System.out.println("Do You wish to continue\n Enter 'n' to dis continue");
    ch=sc.next();
  }
```

}

Error are following:

```
Mar 04, 2015 12:10:58 PM database_connect.Database_connect insertData
SEVERE: null

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'i' in 'field list'
```

Columns in database are "id" and "file".id int(10), file varchar(100)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this statement:

```
 String sql = "INSERT INTO srt(id,file) " +
                   "VALUES (i, s)";
```

To

```
 String sql = "INSERT INTO srt(id,file) " +
               "VALUES ("+i+", '"+s+"')";
```

If you use your stement you have a string not the value of your variables in sql query. So it tries to add the value of a column `i`  and a column `s`  to 'id`and`file`

But the better way is to use prepared statement.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO srt(id,file) " + "VALUES (i, s)";
```

With

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO srt(id,file) " + "VALUES (" + i + ", " + s + ")";
```

You passed the string i and s where as you meant to pass the value of the variables I and s